# Display block/none, function java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am lost. I am working at this: http://dan.jecool.net/tkacma/tkacma.html

It's my first experience with javascript, so sorry for everything you will read there .  :)

my goal is this effect: https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/

i did try to use code from that demo but i get more confused. I do not hope you will type this for me, i need just to direct what I have to use. (i want to show just one div at once and align all the content to top).

thank you for everything.

(hope you understand, it's my first try to write about coding in english).

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bunka">
        <img src="tang.jpg">
        <span onclick="showmefulltang()" class="tang"> 
        <div class="text"> <p>MÍSA TANG</p><p> DESIGN</p></div></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bunka">
        <img src="matys.jpg">
        <span onclick="showmefullmat()" class="mat"> 
        <div class="text"> <p>MATY'S</p> <p>LOGO</p></div> </span>
        </div>

        <div class="bunka">
        <img src="mill.jpg"><span onclick="showmefullmill()" class="mill">
        <div class="text"> <p>MILL</p><p>DESIGN </p></div> </span>
        </div>

        <div class="bunka">
        <img src="zlutahala.jpg">
        <span onclick="showmefullzlut()" class="zlut"> 
        <div class="text"> <p>ZLUTA HALA</p><p>LOGO</p> </div> </span>
        </div>


            <div id="fulltang">
                tang tang tang
            </div>
            <div id="fullmat">
                matis matis matis
            </div>
            <div id="fullmill">
                mill mill mill
            </div>
            <div id="fullzlut">
                zlutahala zlutahala zlutaha
            </div>
```

CSS

```
    .balenibunek {
        margin: 0;
        float:left;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 1360px;
        }

    .bunka {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0px;
        display:inline-block;
        flex:1;
        width: 340px;
        height: 340px;
        }


    .bunka img{
        height:340px;
        }


    .bunka span {
        height:340px;
        width: 340px;
        display:none;
    }
    .bunka span .text {
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 40%;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    }
    .bunka:hover img { 
    display:none;
    }

    .bunka:hover span { 
        display:block;
    }

    .bunka:hover .text {
        -webkit-animation: slide-down 0.7s ease-out;
        -moz-animation: slide-down 0.7s ease-out;
    }

#fulltang {
    background-color: #999999;
    width: 1128px;
    height: 564px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
#fullmat{
    background-color: #999999;
    width: 1128px;
    height: 564px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}

#fullmill{
    background-color: #999999;
    width: 1128px;
    height: 564px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}

#fullzlut{
    background-color: #999999;
    width: 1128px;
    height: 564px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
    function showmefulltang() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fulltang");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}   

function showmefullmat() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fullmat");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}   


function showmefullmill() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fullmill");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}   
function showmefullzlut() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fullzlut");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a mvce including your code

Comment: Could you try to write a complete question here, without relying on links?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'd suggest to see this link [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you.

Comment: edited html/css/javascript code from my page. - my problem as i tried to explain -  want to show just one div at once and align all the content to top after click on some div

Comment: It's a better practice to change CSS with CSS properties. You can give a class using JavaScript and change them properties with this class. Also it's better to encapsulate the same funcionality in a only function. Your example does the same many times depending on the `div` clicked. Take a look to my workaround and ask as many help you need @DanSaginow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate `display: none` to `display: block`. You can achieve a similar result using some kind of active class when the container is clicked.

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<!-- Any HTML content -->
    <div class="hide_content">
    <!-- Any HTML content which will be hidden by default -->
    </div>
</div>
```

On your jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$(".hide_content").on("click", function() {
  $(this).find(".hide_content").toggleClass("active");
});
```

And finally your, CSS:

```
.hide_content{
height: 0;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.active{
height: auto;
}
```

This snippet it's a simple example of a workaround. Your `<div>` is always hidden (with `height:0;`). Clicking the `div`, will trigger the function that toggle `.active` and this will set the height of the element.

Of course you can achieve the same result in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way:

1) Give all your divs the same class and a ID (that is unique for all divs)

2)Write a JS function `function display(ID)` that does the following :
- Use Jquery to read all divs of the specified class into a array
- loop through the array
-> if current ID equals the ID set in the function parameter : set current div to `display: block`
-> else : set current div to `display: none`

3)You will also need a function `function hide(ID)` that will use jquery to select a div by ID and set `display: none`

Hope this will get you going :)

Comment: Identifiers cannot be repeated, your workaround will not work. You can achieve the same with a class, also is more clean and clear.

Comment: Also, you can't animate between both displays, there's another multiple ways to achieve what he is asking for.